# Images Fail to Load, net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, .htaccess, google-chrome

**Problem**

When you load up a page on my site, often times one (or several) images (jpg files that I have saved from Lightroom and/or Photoshop) will not appear. It instead looks like a broken link (ALT description appears) but no image. Hard reload of the browser solves problem (e.g. all images load properly after a hard reload).

**Error Message**

Chrome displays an "ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH" warning for all images it does not load. (Sometimes the image will flash quickly before going to what looks like a dead image)

**Setup**

Running latest version of Wordpress (4.2.2) on a Shared Host. Site is SSL (https) if that matters. Images are located in an image upload folder (nothing complex like Imagemagick, etc) on the host.

**My Troubleshooting**

I have replicated the issue from multiple locations using various ISPs on various machines (both Mac & PC) and with various browsers (Chrome & Safari) some of which are not using any ad-blockers.

What I've tried is the following:

- I asked the host if there was an issue on the server side. They claim no.
- I've tried resetting the functions.php file. No impact.
- I've disabled all plug-ins. No impact.
- I've hardkeyed in the meta charset as UTF-8. No impact.
- Checked if I'm using Gzip. I am not.
- Enabled Wordpress Cache plugin. No impact.
- Cleared .htaccess of all non-necessary redirects & commands. No
  impact.
- Replaced wp-admin and wp-includes folders from fresh install. No
  impact.
- Deleted Wordpress & Reinstalled from a Backup. No dice.
- I've put source code from pages that have this issue into a test.html file and the images seem to load up fine doing that.

**My Thoughts & Questions**

The images are 100-200kb each and sometimes there are a fair amount of them on the page. Is something timing out and then once I hard reload, everything show up because the timeout isn't tripped? That is the best random guess I can gather without understanding the issue perfectly.

Any ideas of things I can try? Should I delete the whole database and start again? Everything I know about computers is self-taught and server issues are not a strong point for me. Even if you don't know what it might be, could someone explain what a content length mismatch is in general terms?

Thanks much!

Comment: are the images on database or web folder? what you mean "Hard reload solves"

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza

The images are uploaded to a web folder. (They are uploaded through the wordpress media uploader but you can see the actual jpg files in the upload folder when browsing it). The link to the image is a direct link to the jpg file in that upload folder

As for hard reload I mean that if I reload the page (ctrl+reload in Chrome) then all images show up.

Comment: Im not familiar with wordpress, but if page load the images with reload my guess the issues in on the browser side. On chrome you press F12 to show console window to see what is happen in the network that can give you a hint.

Comment: Also my guess is images are public, so you can do a `test.html` pointing to the image and try to show it.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Correct, the "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH" error comes from Chromes console.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Note that I have replicated this error on Safari as well as Chrome. I think the browser is programmed to not load the image when there is this "mismatch" whereas other browsers might ignore this error. When you say to do a test.html, are you saying to replicate the HTML and see if it occurs outside of wordpress itself? I can try that.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza So I tried putting the source of three different pages into a test.html file and all images are loading up fine.

Comment: If the website is public, could you share the url of a page where you have the issue ?

Comment: Because you could load the image, then the problem maybe the wordpress project. I suggest try to start with a new wordpress, do something simple and start build up. Also another try in the browser... use the console and disable cache. That way browser will look for the url each time.

Comment: you've already answered your own question, when you reload  (im not sure what you mean by hard reload CRTL + f5?) the page, the browser cache serves the images. It is either the browser or the server which times out. Try resizing the images and optimizing with tinypng if you need a lot of them or load in with js when they become visible, etc. But a 200kb image is probably overkill.

Comment: @DavidDuponchel https://triphash.com/travel-blog is the site. The blog entries are where the photos typically do not appear. (Sometimes they do, sometimes they do not).

Comment: Thank you for the ideas @David. I will try to resizing angle to see if that helps. Since the images seem to appear when they are coded in hard HTML, it does make me thing perhaps that Wordpress/PHP is the culprit and maybe I will do more testing to see how much imagery I can post in strict HTML. Very helpful.

Comment: Thank you @JuanCarlosOropeza. Rebuilding the Wordpress from scratch will be something I resort to if nothing else works.

Comment: they work everytime when inserted statically? Check the url, i've had problems before with timthumb, php would not be anything to do with it, all it does is echo the url.

Answer (score 7):

When you request data from a web server, it responds first with some information about the data (HTTP headers)  and *then* with the data. One of these pieces of information, an HTTP header, is called `Content-Length`. It tells the client how much data it should expect to receive from the server. When your browser gets an image, the server's response (very simplified looks like)

```
Content-Length: 100000

< the image, 100000 bytes of data >
```

The client knows the request is complete when it has received the amount of data told by `Content-Length`. Until it receives in this case 100KB (100000 bytes), it considers the image, for example, to not be done loading.

*If* the server breaks the request before the client receives the data from the server, or if the client receives more data than it received, the client will throw some sort of error and assume the data to be corrupted/unusable and dispose of it. How this is handled can vary between browsers.

How did you upload the images to your website? Myself, I have encountered this problem in a situation where the file's *supposed* size was stored in the database, and this was used to set the `Content-Length` header. The file size in the DB wasn't correct for the file. **HOWEVER,** I know that WordPress does **not** store file sizes in the database; media uploads are simply represented by a URL.

This could also happen if the web server runs out of resources and can no longer fulfill your requests; you said you had lots of images per page. If you are on a really lousy shared hosting plan, it may be the case that the host imposes limits, or that the server simply can't handle the traffic of all the sites it hosts.

Comment: Thank you so much. That is a very clear summation. Understanding the "why" is always so helpful.

I will look into the host angle.

Comment: I got a failed request and a successful request (with `TripHash-2001-3255-Seoul-Fish-Market.jpg` for example): I get a `Content-Length:  217045` in both cases. In the failed request I get only the first 96kB of the image, in the successful request I get all the 212kB. I reproduced the issue with Firefox and Chrome. I still don't know what triggers the issue.

Comment: Thanks @DavidDuponchel. At the moment, server-side compression settings are being investigated. This has been perplexing me for a while. It is helpful to know that you got it to happen in Firefox. Since it impacts Gecko, Webkit and Blink, I think browser engine error can be thrown out as well.

Comment: kudos to the concise explanation. much obliged

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to circle back on this in case someone else is experiencing this problem. It appears that there is some type of glitch between HTTPS and image retrieval that was causing the problem. While I don't understand WHY that is, I converted my site from SSL/HTTPS to simple HTTP (which I was able to do as it doesn't require encryption) and it appears all images load as they should.

If someone understands the "why", I'd love to understand what the issue actually is. Luckily, I was able to come up with workaround. So, while this doesn't answer my question, it does provide context of what is causing the problem and my common sense workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You might see this problem with a shared hosting service. Free bandwidth is like free speech, not free beer. Resource outage policies are invoked during traffic spikes.

A distributed system architecture solves this by inserting a front-end CDN tier (eg. CloudFlare). CDNs cache your static resources and can vastly reduce the load on your host. In fact, for completely static sites the host can be shut down.

There are other advantages to CDNs, like attack detection, free SSL (not beer) and overall improved performance and security compared to shared hosting alone.

Many CDNs are free (as in speech). You could also upgrade to private hosting, but $ and you still might want a front-end tier.